# When doing performance analysis with JProfiler, can I display a sliding-window-last-X-seconds view?

Tags: java, jprofiler

I have a java application that, from time to time, seems to have hiccups where it lags a lot / becomes unresponsive for a few seconds, then continues like normal again. This isn't associated with any disk or network output, but CPU usage goes way up for a short time when this happens.

I'd like to use JProfiler to see what happens during that time, but I don't know what triggers the behaviour (so I can't just move my application to that point, then start CPU recording), and leaving CPU recording on all the time until a hiccup occurs doesn't help much either, since that will include the CPU percentages of everything up to that point in the calculation, distracting from what's using CPU *now*.

So what I'd like is a view that shows me "average CPU usage by method over the last X seconds", that throws away all data that's older than X seconds automatically, and calculates just the averages over those last X samples (assuming 1 sample per second). I wasn't able to find any option that allows me to do this; is this something that JProfiler just doesn't support, or haven't I looked hard enough?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of exceptional circumstances can be analyzed with JProfiler's "exceptional method runs" feature.

In the call tree, select the method that shows the performance spike and select "Add As Exceptional Method" from the context menu.

Then, you can see the slowest invocations separately with all other invocations merged into a single node:

[image]

This screen cast shows the entire feature:

http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2011/02/methods-statistics-and-exceptional.html